# Not able to send the keys to the input element

Tags: java, mobile, appium, appium-android

I'm trying to pass the login credentials to the input fields, everytime when I run the code the input field is getting identified, but the keys are not passing at the input field. Please help...

```
Code:
WebElement image=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Image[@content-desc='LandingPAge']"));
System.out.println("Landed Login page");
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='Username']").sendKeys("u3@gmail.com");
driver.findElementById("password").sendKeys("1231212");
driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='Login']").click();

Appium Log Details: 
[debug] [W3C (235592b3)] Calling AppiumDriver.setValue() with args: [["u","3","@","g","m","a","i","l",".","c","o","m"],"2","235592b3-a8eb-4ccb-8d22-fef43fa92679"]
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:setText","params":{"elementId":"2","text":"u3@gmail.com","replace":false}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:setText","params":{"elementId":"2","text":"u3@gmail.com","replace":false}}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: setText
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using element passed in: 2
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Attempting to clear using UiObject.clearText().
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"UiSelector[CLASS=android.view.View, INSTANCE=5]"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
[debug] [W3C (235592b3)] Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchElementError: UiSelector[CLASS=android.view.View, INSTANCE=5]

Ecllipse Console Error:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
Jun 05, 2019 1:03:25 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Landed Login page
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass setUp
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
UiSelector[CLASS=android.view.View, INSTANCE=5]
For documentation on this error, please visit:
http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Comment: try `driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Username").sendKeys("u3@gmail.com");`

Comment: For one thing, you're probably getting the wrong elements - views are just views, you should be sending text to an EditText.  It's also suspicious that you're using WebElement instead of MobileElement, but without seeing your driver initialization code we have no idea if that applies or not.

Answer (score 0):

Although you're following like selenium sendKeys to enter text in input fields, sometimes appium does not work as it.

So first click on input field and then enter value using sendKeys as mentioned in below snippet.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("#loc")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("#loc")).sendKeys("text);
```

Let me know if you still face any issue.